# value error not enough values left to unpack

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

hey so i was writing a code which first inputs the number of students then asks the user for the name and marks in 3 subjects, what i want to do is to accept the name/position of the student and display his/her name and score and the average marks

heres the code:

```
lst = []
n=int(input("Enter number of students:"))

for i in range(0,n):
    x=input("Enter name:")
    y=int(input("Enter physics marks:"))
    z=int(input("Enter maths marks:"))
    a=int(input("Enter chemistry marks:"))

    avg=(y+z+a)/3


    lst.append((x,y,z,a,avg,))

b=int(input("Enter the number of the student:"))

for x,y,z,a,avg in lst[b-1]:
    print(x,":",y,z,a,avg,)
    print(x,avg,)
```

im getting this error:

```
for x,y,z,a,avg in lst[b-1]:
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 3)
```

any improvement is appreciated as im new to python , thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

The fix is to remove the `for` loop.

```
lst = []
n=int(input("Enter number of students:"))

for i in range(0,n):
    x=input("Enter name:")
    y=int(input("Enter physics marks:"))
    z=int(input("Enter maths marks:"))
    a=int(input("Enter chemistry marks:"))

    avg=(y+z+a)/3


    lst.append((x,y,z,a,avg,))

b=int(input("Enter the number of the student:"))

x,y,z,a,avg = lst[b-1]
print(x,":",y,z,a,avg,)
print(x,avg,)
```

Explanation:

Sample session:

```
Enter number of students:1
Enter name:fred
Enter physics marks:30
Enter maths marks:21
Enter chemistry marks:23
Enter the number of the student:1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "----", line 17, in <module>
    for x,y,z,a,avg in lst[b-1]:
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 4)
```

The issue is that Python tries to iterate the values. The value of `lst[b-1]` is `('fred', 30, 21, 23, 24.666666666666668)`. You've told it to make the variables `x,y,z,a,avg` out of it, so it tries with the first item: `'fred'`. This only has four characters, not five as it would like to unpack into, so it throws an error.

To fix it, we simply tell Python to make the whole of `lst[b-1]` into five variables, not the just its first item.

Answer (score 0):

If you are printing only one student you don't need a `for` for that, something like this should work:

```py
x,y,z,a,avg = lst[b-1]

print(x,":",y,z,a,avg)
print(x,avg)
```

And the error happens because you are running a `for` for only one student since `lst[b-1]` is a student.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating a list of lists. then to iterate over them you should.

```
for sub_list in list:
    print(sub_list)
```

If you want to print out the b-nth student then you can just use:

```
print(lst[b-1])
('John', 5, 4, 3, 4.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a list for each mater BUT IN THE SAME ORDER AS STUDENT: try this code you'ill understand what i mean and be able to adapt to your purpose:

```
student = ['xavier', 'lucy','anna','leo']
math = [2,8,5,6]
phys = [8,5,6,7]

l = []
for s,m,p in zip(student, math,phys):
    l.append((s,m,p))
n=int(input('Which student?'))
print('the full info',l[n])
print('\nonly name and phys :) :\n',l[n][0], l[n][2])
```